# "that is" in speech

Tags: formal-language, informal-language, formality, register

When "that is" means "in other words," can it be used in colloquial speech? Or is it more suited to a formal register? Does the following sound natural in daily speech?

> We, **that is**, my brother and I, are going there tomorrow.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: **that is** is perfectly good in all registers including informal, and slightly better than **in other words** when you are clarifying the meaning, not the wording.

Answer (score -1):

When "that is" means "in other words," can it be used in colloquial speech? Or is it more suited to a formal register? Does the following sound natural in daily speech?

**We, that is, my brother and I, are going there tomorrow.**

To be Honest no it does not sound correct I believe you should have used the saying

***We, I should say, my brother and I, are going there tomorrow.****

**"that is" adds nothing to the sentence**, without saying "that is" it is already assumed from the sentence **We, my brother and I, are going there tomorrow.**

Whilst **"I should say" denotes a correction**. You have remembered **they do not know who we are?**

Further more  **"in other words,**" does not work in this situation either. **"in other words,**" is used when you give an explanation instead of a direct reply to a question or  a reason to not comply with a suggestion, rather than giving a short direct answer like yes or no.

*We, my brother and I, are going there tomorrow., **"In other words,**" I'm busy and won't be available.

Comment: How about "that is to say" instead of "that is" in the OP?